# UV Unwrap model as multiple flat straight strips

Tags: uv

I'm trying to create tank tracks for my own game engine. I want to scroll the UVs so that it looks like the track is moving. I used 'Follow Active Quads' as a start. This helped immensely for the tops and bottoms of the tracks. They only needed a little bit of editing (mirroring/scaling). Unfortunately the sides of the tracks are still curved. As you can see here:

[image: uvs]

After a lot of manual editing I got them straightened out:

[image: straight uvs]

However doing so I made the faces of the sides no longer correspond to the area of the faces in the model. Now I'm starting to think there has to be a faster/less manual way to do this. But after a lot of searching I have not yet struck the right keyword. Does anybody know a good technique to do this?

For reference, here is my 3D model, complete with seams.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still some manual editing ............

1. Remove the outer edge seams so that those sides will be attached to the outer face UV islands when unwrapped.
2. Select those outer faces and sides and unwrap using the Conformal method.

[image]

3. Select only the inner faces and unwrap.
4. In the UV editor move these new UV islands to the right so that they will not be overlapping the outer faces UV's.

[image]

5. In the UV editor straighten out edges where necessary.

[image]

If you need to separate the sides UV's from the outer faces UV's.......

6. In the UV Editor, select two edges that make up one of the sides and hit the  <kbd>Y</kbd>  (to separate)  <kbd>X</kbd>  (to confine in the X axis)  <kbd>G</kbd>  to move and drag the new island away to clear space on the UV square.
7. Repeat for the other 3 sides.

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, I didn't know about conformal, and its nice to see how it all works out when removing one set of seams.